# Julia: Initializing numeric arrays of different types

Tags: arrays, types, type-conversion, julia, variable-declaration

I am trying to build a two element array in Julia, where each sub-array has a different type (one is a vector of `Int64`s, the other is an array of `Float32`s).

The code belows automatically converts the element that I want to be an `Int64` into a `Float32`, which is what I don't want:

```
my_multitype_array = [ collect(1:5), rand(Float32,3) ]
```

The resulting array automatically converts the `Int64`s in the first array (defined via `collect(1:5)`) into a `Float32`, and the resulting `my_multitype_array` has type `2-element Array{Array{Float32,1}}`. How do I force it to make the first sub-array remain `Int64`s? Do I need to perhaps pre-define `my_multitype_array` to be an empty array with two elements of the desired types, before filling it out with values?

And finally, once I *do* have the desired array with different types, how would I refer to it, when pre-stating its type in a function? See below for what I mean:

```
function foo_function(first_scalar_arg::Float32, multiple_array_arg::Array{Array{Float32,1}})
       # do stuff
       return
end
```

Instead of `::Array{Array{Float32,1}}`, would I write `::Array{Array{Any,1}}` or something?

Comment: As in the answers you get you can use a Union type. But you could also think if the outer structure would be a tuple rather than an array. That would be likely even more efficient, as it would know the two inner types at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the following code matches better what was asked in the question:

```
julia> a = Union{Array{Int},Array{Float64}}[[1,2,3],rand(2,2)]
2-element Array{Union{Array{Float64,N} where N, Array{Int64,N} where N},1}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [0.834902264215698 0.42258382777543124; 0.5856562680004389 0.6654033155981287]
```

This creates an actual data structure which knows that it contains either `Float64` or `Int` arrays.

Some usage

```
julia> a[1]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> a[2]
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.834902  0.422584
 0.585656  0.665403
```

And manipulating the structure:

```
julia> push!(a, [1, 1]); #works

julia> push!(a, [true, false]);
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Union{Array{Float64,N} where N, Array{Int64,N} where N}(::Array{Bool,1})
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Regarding the second part of the question (annotating the type in a function), would I then pre-state the type of the argument as `arg::Array{Union{Array{Float64,N} where N, Array{Int64,N} where N},1}`?

Comment: You do not need to write `where N` unless you need the information about  `N` in the function body. Hence normally it is enough to write  `arg::Vector{Union{Array{Float64}, Array{Int64}}}`. However, if you need the information about array sizes in type than it gets far more complicated. For an example if the dimensionality depends on type of elements you could have `function f(arg::Vector{Union{Array{Float64,N1}, Array{Int64,N2}}}) where {N1,N2}`

Answer (score 3):

### How to instantiate a vector of different types:

If you type the vector in a terminal, it will be promoted to the largest common type:

```
julia> [[1], [1.0]]
2-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [1.0]
 [1.0]
```

The reason for that is that you don't specify the type of the outer vector, so Julia will try to infer the type based on the contents. More specific types are always more efficient, so if the vector types can be converted to a single type that can represent all the inner vectors, this will be done (through the `promote` mechanism). To avoid it, you need to manually specify the outer vector type e.g.:

```
julia> Any[[1], [1.0]]
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 [1]
 [1.0]
```

### How to refer to vectors of differently-typed vectors

When you think about it, "vectors of differently-typed vectors" is not a single type, but an *infinite set of types*. These kind of types are called "unionall types" in Julia, and are represented by the `where` keyword. In this case, you want `Vector{T} where T <: Vector`.

But wait! Then how come:

```
julia> Any[[1], [1.0]] isa Vector{T} where T <: Vector
false
```

Well, a vector that can contain any element is not really a *vector of vectors*. So here you have two options:

- Either relax your function signature by just removing the type annotations or relatixing them significantly (this is preferred because the value you pass in may actually be a vector of vectors even if its type is e.g. `Vector{Any}`):

```
function foo_function(first_scalar_arg, multiple_array_arg::AbstractArray)
       # do stuff
       return
end
```

- Or else be vigilant that you make sure to construct a "vector of vectors" initially:

```
julia> Vector[[1], [1.0]]
2-element Array{Array{T,1} where T,1}:
 [1]
 [1.0]

julia> Vector[[1], [1.0]] isa Vector{T} where T <: Vector
true
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I accepted the other answer since it was a more direct and appropriate answer to the question that I originally asked, but your answer was actually more appropriate/educative for me, in terms of explaining the various concepts tangential to this question, so it's much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

To expand a little on @Przemyslaw Szufel's answer...

Creating vectors with elements of mixed types is tricky, as you've seen, since the literal array constructor attempts to promote the elements to a common type. There is a special syntax to get around that, which is described in the manual [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Typed-array-literals-1).

In your case, you can construct your vector of vectors as follows:

```
julia> Union{Vector{Int64}, Vector{Float32}}[[1, 2], [1.0f0, 2.0f0]]
2-element Array{Union{Array{Float32,1}, Array{Int64,1}},1}:
 [1, 2]
 Float32[1.0, 2.0]
```

The prefix to the literal array constructor specifies the element type of the array. So in this case, the element type of the vector is constrained to be

```
Union{Vector{Int64}, Vector{Float32}}
```

In other words, the elements of the outer vector must be either vectors of `Int64` or vectors of `Float32`.

Comment: the way you wrote it is actually nicer than mine so I updated my answer. Of course `(T where T<:Union{Array{Int},Array{Float64}}) === Union{Array{Int},Array{Float64}}` is `true` and hence I overused the parenthesis.